# MySQL group by and counter

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table having fields  user, bookname having following records

[image]

and i execute the following query

```
SELECT `bookname`,`user`, count(*) as total FROM `books` GROUP BY `bookname`,`user`
```

i got following output

[image]

And i am expecting this output

```
bookname  user  total 
a          u1    2 
b          u1    1
a          u2     1
b          u2     0
```

and i don't have third table.

Any idea what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6f8c/12

```
SELECT s.bookname, s.user, IF(t.count IS NULL, s.count, t.count) FROM 
(
  SELECT bookname, user, 0 AS `count` FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT bookname FROM books) AS p,
  (SELECT DISTINCT user FROM books) AS q
) AS s LEFT JOIN
(SELECT bookname, user, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM books GROUP BY bookname, user) AS t
ON (s.bookname = t.bookname AND s.user = t.user)
```

Result

```
a    u1   2
b    u1   1
a    u2   1
b    u2   0
```